Docker is downgrading SSL for MySQL connection
The server
I have a MySQL server v8.4 running in Google Cloud with skip-name-resolve. It requires SSL connections, but without trusted client certificates.
I have a user configured on the server to connect from any IP: 'myuser'@'%'.
I have verified the user can connect from any IP using the mysql DB where SELECT Host, User FROM user returns:
+-----------+----------------------------+
| Host      | User                       |
+-----------+----------------------------+
| %         | myuser                     |
| %         | root                       |
+-----------+----------------------------+

For Google Cloud config, connections are allowed from any IP, set using the CIDR range 0.0.0.0/0.
The client
I have a Python program using SQLAlchemy to connect to the server:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

with Session(create_engine('mysql://myuser:mypass@X.X.X.X:3306/mydb?ssl=true')) as session:
    result = session.query(MyTable).all()
    print(result)

When running on my local machine, this connects to the remote server without issue and prints the rows. Using a VPN and switching to various IP addresses, this continues to work.
The problem
As soon as I put this client code inside a Docker container, the server starts denying the connections.
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'myuser'@'Y.Y.Y.Y' (using password: YES)")

Y.Y.Y.Y matches my public IP address exactly. Connecting from outside the Docker container from this same IP address does not have any issues.
My Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12-slim-bullseye

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONPATH=.

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY myfile.py myfile.py

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y pkg-config default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD python3 myfile.py

The database logs show that the request is reaching the server but provides no additional information:
Access denied for user 'myuser'@'Y.Y.Y.Y' (using password: YES)

Disabling the SSL requirement on the server fixes the issue. So it seems that the container is ignoring the ?ssl=true.
How do I get the container's connection to use SSL?

"It requires SSL connections, but without trusted client certificates."  I suspect ssl setup that was performed on the host, was not performed on the server.  Do you need an extra CA certificate or an (untrusted) client cert?

There is no certificate requirement. The local machine I am using has no certificates and connects without issue.

In your connection string, add ?ssl_mode=REQUIRED instead of ?ssl=true. This is the syntax for libmysqlclient (MySQL docs confusingly refer to ssl-mode and sslMode which are not available with libmysqlclient).
